# How to position a column under another column?

Tags: mobile, html-table

I am currently working on a website that is mobile friendly. In this case I have to use the same HTML. I can make do some minor adjustments but it MUST look like the same when I change it back to this default CSS.

```css
#explain{
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:20px;
 width:95%;
 min-width:0;
 margin:auto;
 column-count:1;
}#explain th{
 margin:0px;
}#explain_icon img{
 width:130px;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table id="explain"  cellspacing="15px">
                <tr id="explain_icon">
                   <td><img src="IMG/group.png" alt="Image has failed to load"></td>
                   <td><img src="IMG/Bell.png" alt="Image has failed to load"></td>
                   <td><img src="IMG/Warrenty.png" alt="Image has failed to load"></td>
                </tr><tr>
                   <th>Japan</th>
                   <th>is a</th>
                   <th>smaller china</th>
                </tr><tr>
                      <td><b>The
                      </b></td>
                      <td><b>Human
                      </b></td>
                      <td><b>Esophagus
                      </b></td>
            </tr></table>
  
  </body>
  <html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap. Integrate Bootstrap in your website and just divide your html page in row and column classes. This is perfect way to make any website mobile friendly.

Comment: I would prefer not to use bootstrap due to my lack of knowledge with it as well as the fact that I would have to rewrite all my code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by changing the table into a divider format. I also made a list for the individual objects within the code. I went into the CSS and changed it so that the display would go into "table" which basically made everything columns.